# CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

As the title suggests, I'm making a CSS dropdown menu.

My first problem was that when I hovered, the dropdown menu covered the hamburger icon. So I added `margin-top` which fixed that issue but caused another. When I would move my mouse off of the hamburger icon to select one of the drop down options, the dropdown menu would disappear. So my question is, how can I have a dropdown menu, which still displays the hamburger icon on display and lets me actually click the options without disappearing.

```css
/* Global Styles */

* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
/* Nav Bar Styling */

div.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
span.dropbutton {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 2%
}
#lines:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
/* Dropdown Styling */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color:
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <span id="title">Title</span>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropbutton">☰</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: no answer accepted yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using absolute position on .dropdown-content so on that css I just add top:35px . If you have any question ask me in comment :)

```css
/* Global Styles */

* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;

}
/* Nav Bar Styling */

div.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
span.dropbutton {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 2%
}
#lines:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
/* Dropdown Styling */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top:35px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color:
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <span id="title">Title</span>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropbutton">☰</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this is basically what I tried, it has the same issue. you can't actually click any of the options before it disappears. try it out

Comment: @oneman Update the answer basically you set inline-block to dropdown class with position relative. And on .dropdown:hover you set display:block. So I just remove the display inline-block from dropdown call.. Rest are same :) good luck

Answer (score 1):

Something like this,

Giving `height` and `width` to `.dropdown` and `top:100%;` to `.dropdown-content` will solve problem

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 100%;
}
```

```css
/* Global Styles */

* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
/* Nav Bar Styling */

div.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
span.dropbutton {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 2%
}
#lines:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
/* Dropdown Styling */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 100%;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color:
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <span id="title">Title</span>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropbutton">☰</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a padding to the menu container, remove the background color to make it transparent and add the background-color to the elements of the menu

```css
/* Global Styles */

* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
/* Nav Bar Styling */

div.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
span.dropbutton {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 2%
}
#lines:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
/* Dropdown Styling */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 36px;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color:
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <span id="title">Title</span>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropbutton">☰</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lower the dropdown-content by 20px. This way there won't be a gap between the hamburger icon and the sub-menu. A gap disables the hover effect.

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the last selector

```
.dropdown:hover{display:block;}
.dropdown:blur{display:none;}
```

OR
You may you javascript for this task.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("dropdown").onfocus = function () {
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = block;
    }   
    document.getElementById("dropdown").onblur = function () {
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = none;
    }   
</script>
```

Add this script just before ending body tag